# TCPDF for setting margins

Tags: tcpdf

I am generating `PDF` file using `TCPDF`, when I try to use inbuilt functions for setting margin, i.e. `$pdf->SetMargins()`, it doesn't work. My main purpose for it to remove extra space for `ul` and `li` tags, because it is disturbing my pdf format and text content mixing into each other.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set margins is for the document itself and it will not affect the ul or lis on the document. You got to set the styling for those yourself. One tip is to do the styling all inline (just pretend that you building up a page for 1990).